# How to pass binding to subview with SwiftUI when the variable is nested in an object?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This works

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var val1: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        MySubview(val1: $val1)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(val1: 0)
    }
}
#endif

struct MySubview : View {
    @Binding var val1: Int
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Value = \(val1)")
    }
}
```

But when the variable is nested in an Object, this fails

```
import SwiftUI
struct MyStruct {
    let number: Int
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var val1 = MyStruct(number: 7)
    var body: some View {
        MySubview(val1: $val1.number)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(val1: 0)
    }
}
#endif

struct MySubview : View {
    @Binding var val1: Int
    var body: some View {
        return Text("Value = \(val1)")
    }
}
```

Error shown: `Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred`

How do i pass nested variable as a binding to a subview?

Comment: Could the people giving negative votes explain why? The questions was very clear.

Comment: @MartinR i have now changed to code to have self contained copy & paste code.

Comment: Some negative votes I do not understand! The error you were getting was very misleading and it is an honest answer. Check mine below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is very misleading. Number must be a var, not a let:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    var number: Int
}
```

Change it and it will work fine.

Comment: Also, your preview is wrong: You should create your view like this ```ContentView()```, not ```ContentView(val1: 0)```

Comment: XCode error messages were highly misleading in this case

Comment: With SwiftUI you cannot trust any error! Not even its location. Sometimes an error at the top of you code is produced by something all the way down at the bottom (or in another file). It is very annoying, I hope they improve it over time.

Comment: Seems obvious to me but just to confirm. Is that because MyStruct.number can be changed by the @State var val1 property, so it need to be mutable?

Comment: Im finding SwiftUI's errors to be more problematic than the bugs that they are trying to describe. It doesn't help development when the tools that are meant to point out errors in your code are in themselves buggy and errornous!

Answer (score 8):

Your code was good except for needing `var number: Int` as kontiki pointed out.

To help with understanding of passing bindings about between views I prepared the following code which shows use of `@Binding` in slightly different ways:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Zoo    { var shed:    Shed     }
struct Shed   { var animals: [Animal] }
struct Animal { var legs:    Int      }

struct ZooView : View {
  @State var zoo = Zoo( shed: Shed(animals:
      [ Animal(legs: 2), Animal(legs: 4) ] ) )

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Legs in the zoo directly:")
      Text("Animal 1 Legs: \(zoo.shed.animals[0].legs)")
      Text("Animal 2 Legs: \(zoo.shed.animals[1].legs)")
      Divider()
      Text("And now with nested views:")
      ShedView(shed: $zoo.shed)
    }
  }
}

struct ShedView : View {
  @Binding var shed: Shed

  var body: some View {
    ForEach(shed.animals.indices) { index in
      VStack {
        Text("Animal: \(index+1)")
        AnimalView(animal: self.$shed.animals[index])
      }
    }
  }
}

struct AnimalView : View {
  @Binding var animal: Animal

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Legs = \(animal.legs)")
      Button(
      action: { self.animal.legs += 1 }) {
        Text("Another leg")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In particular `ShedView` is given a binding to a shed and it looks up an animal in the array of animals in the shed and passes a binding to the animal on to `AnimalView`.

Comment: How would you make `self.animal.legs += 1` run in a view model inside of `AnimalView`?